Debugger error occurring in Oxygen but not in normal transformation run
I'm using Oxygen 24 with Saxon-EE 9.9.1.7 and I'm trying to run XSLT in the debugger but it fails to run however if I just run it outside of the debugger it does run?
I'm running an XSLT over the following source XML doc:
    <MSG02>
      <IDOC BEGIN="1">
          <E1EDK01 SEGMENT="1">
              <BELNR>1</BELNR>
          </E1EDK01>
        <E1EDK03 SEGMENT="1">
          <IDDAT>001</IDDAT>
          <DATUM>20240430</DATUM>
        </E1EDK03>
        <E1EDKT1 SEGMENT="1">
          <TDID>Z001</TDID>
          <TSSPRAS>D</TSSPRAS>
          <TSSPRAS_ISO>DE</TSSPRAS_ISO>
          <E1EDKT2 SEGMENT="1">
            <TDLINE>POconfType:accept;</TDLINE>
            <TDFORMAT>=</TDFORMAT>
          </E1EDKT2>
        </E1EDKT1>
        <E1EDKT1 SEGMENT="1">
          <TDID>Z001</TDID>
          <TSSPRAS>E</TSSPRAS>
          <TSSPRAS_ISO>EN</TSSPRAS_ISO>
          <E1EDKT2 SEGMENT="1">
            <TDLINE>POconfType:accept;</TDLINE>
            <TDFORMAT>=</TDFORMAT>
          </E1EDKT2>
        </E1EDKT1>
      </IDOC>
    </MSG02>

With the following XSLT:
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
        exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
        <xsl:param name="xquery-param1" as="xs:string" expand-text="no"><![CDATA[
                element E1EDKT1 {attribute SEGMENT {"1"}, 
                    element TDID { "ZG04" }, 
                        if (exists(/*/IDOC/E1EDKT1[TDID="ZG04"]/E1EDKT2/TDLINE)) then 
                            (element TSSPRAS {"E"},
                             element TSSPRAS_ISO {"EN"},
                                for $kt in (/*/IDOC/E1EDKT1[TDID="ZG04"][1]/E1EDKT2/TDLINE)
                                return
                                    element E1EDKT2 {attribute SEGMENT {"1"},
                                    $kt
                                    }
                            )
                        else(),
                        if (exists(/*/IDOC/E1EDK01/BELNR)) then
                            ( element E1EDKT2 {attribute SEGMENT {"1"},
                              element TDLINE { concat("DateOfSupply:",/*/IDOC/E1EDK03[IDDAT="001"]/DATUM/concat(substring(.,1,4),"-",substring(.,5,2),"-",substring(.,7,2))) }
                              }
                            )
                        else()
                }
      ]]></xsl:param>
        <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:variable name="xquery1" select="saxon:compile-query($xquery-param1)"/>
        <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="E1EDKT1[1]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="saxon:query($xquery1)"/>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>


Before debugging I get the following warning:

For parameter 'xquery-param1, the variable/parameter $kt should be placed in a 'Text Value Template'

When I run the debugger I get:

W Evaluation will always throw a dynamic error: Namespace prefix {myfunc} has not been declared
E Internal error evaluating template rule at line 29 in module file:/C:/...

The error stops the debugger from completing whereas if I do a normal run it generates an output as expected?

I think you can safely ignore the warning For parameter 'xquery-param1, the variable/parameter $kt should be placed in a 'Text Value Template', it is just some (Schematron?) based syntax checker that fails for your special use case to understand that the text string inside of the parameter/variable is not meant to be XSLT but XQuery that you evaluate separately.

I can't reproduce the error when debugging in the current version of oXygen with Saxon 12 EE, let's wait to see what the oXygen guys will say.

OK fair comment @Martin, however the internal error is the one that's a real problem for me as it stops me from using the debugger

Line 29 is <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>, no? As I said, I don't have that version of oXygen but are you sure that for debugging you selected both the XML input source and the XSLT stylesheet? Because I got an error on my first debugging intent on that line when I had switched from editing to debugging and as the XML and the XSLT was open in oXygen I thought it would run the XSLT against the XML but it didn't, I first had to select it again/explicitly as the input in a select box of the debugger.

Usually such "internal error" problems indicate an unhandled error in the XSLT processor. I would suggest you get a trial license of the latest Oxygen 26.1 and try to use it to debug the same XML/XSLT combination, if that works, this means there was a bug in the XSLT processor bundled with Oxygen 24 which was subsequently fixed. If you still have the same problem with Oxygen 26.1, please contact the Oxygen XML team directly.

My license has allowed me to download 24.1 and I was quite delighted to see that the debugger now works :). However this now means that I'm developing solutions with Saxon EE 10.6 and my Server runtime uses Saxon EE 9.9.1.7. Is there a way to allow Oxgen 24.1 to work with the older Saxon engine?

I can't tell for that oXygen 24.x version but usually you can install additional Saxon versions (some older as the preinstalled, sometimes newer as the preinstalled) as oXygen plugins; as far as I remember they can then only be used for XSLT execution, not for debugging, but perhaps debugging with Saxon EE 10.6 if necessary and then running with Saxon EE 9.9 is a compromise for you to get your code both working with the debugger in oXygen and executable for the runtime environment where I understand you depend on EE 9.9.

I've now successfully imported the older version of the Saxon XSLT processor, as per your instructions, all working in one application version now - @Martin thank you for your advice on it.
